# How do I use the `Headers` iterator in the browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, ecmascript-6, iterator

I am trying to use the `Headers` iterator per the [Iterator docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).

```
  let done = false
  while ( ! done ) {
    let result = headers.entries()
    if ( result.value ) {
      console.log(`yaay`)
    } 
    if ( result.done ) {
      console.log(`finished`)
      done = true
    } 
  }
```

I receive the TypeScript error:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IterableIterator<[string, string]>'.
```

But according to the spec, the property `value` should exist on any Iterator, and the `headers.entries()` returns an Iterator.

**How do I get the values out of a Headers object?**

Comment: `done` and `value` are properties on the object returned from `next()`.

Comment: @tkausl ah that's it - do you want to add that as an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 0):

> But according to the spec, the property `value` should exist on any `Iterator`

No, it exists on the iterator result object that the `Iterator`'s `.next()` method returns. So you'd do

```
const iter = headers.entries();
let { value, done } = iter.next();
while (!done) {
    console.log('yay', value);
    ({ value, done } = iter.next());
}
console.log('finished');
```

However, you'd never implement the iteration protocol yourself. You just use `for … of`:

```
for (const value of headers.entries()) {
    console.log('yay', value);
}
console.log('finished');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Array.from(headers)` and use regular map/forEach methods to manipulate.

```js
const headers= new Headers({some: 'thing'})

Array.from(headers).forEach(([key,val])=>{console.log(key,val)})
```